Computing a higher Tor group of graded modules over specific graded ring
I'm interested in computing $\operatorname{Tor}^{R_*}_2(M_*, N_*)_0$, where $M_*, N_*$ are $\mathbb{Z}$-graded modules concentrated in degrees 0,1 and $R_*$ is the $\mathbb{Z}$-graded ring $\mathbb{Z}[\eta]/(2 \eta, \eta^2)$ (where $\eta$ has degree 1). I conjecture this group is $0$, but need some assistance proving it.
For background context, I am interested in finding the image of the differential in a (Kunneth spectral sequence) $d^2_{2,0}$ which maps this Tor group to $\operatorname{Tor}^{R_*}_0(M_*, N_*)_1$. Essentially, I'm trying to compute the homotopy groups of a truncation of the relative smash product (over a truncation of the sphere spectrum) of two stable homotopy 1-types. So if my suspicion below is wrong, any clues about this image are appreciated.
My suspicion is that the Tor group of interest will be trivial because when I try to naively take a (homogeneous) projective resolution of $M_*$, it seems as if the internal degree increases as the homological degree increases. However, I'm not sure how to formalize the intuition that at homological degree 2, there is no contribution from internal degree 0. One guess is that maybe $\operatorname{Tor}^{R_*}_p(M_*, N_*)_0 \cong \operatorname{Tor}^{R_0}_p(M_0, N_0)$, since given a projective resolution $P_{*,*}$ of $M_*$, I think $P_{*,0}$ is a projective resolution of $M_0$ and $(P_{p,*} \otimes_{R_*} N_*)_0 \cong P_{p,0} \otimes_{R_0} N_0$. But I'm not sure if that's a legal move.
This is my first hands-on experience with a spectral sequence and my background in homological algebra is too weak to know how to generalize what I know about $\operatorname{Tor}$ for rings to the graded ring context. Is there a short argument for this kind of thing, or standard reference? I was referred to the chapter on minimal resolutions in Eisenbud's "Introduction to Commutative Algebra" where he treats the case that $R$ is a local ring and claims the reader can easily generalize to when $R$ is a graded polynomial ring over a field, but I lack the sophistication to generalize to my setting.
